# Why whole db displays in index action view as a plain text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I created some simple app to upload pictures with paperclip gem. Somehow whole db displays in index action view (look at the screenshot below)

[image: WTF]

Here is part of my pic controller:

```
def index
    @pics = Pic.all
end
```

Here is my index view:

```
<h1>Index here</h1>
<div class="index">
    <%= @pics.each do |pic| %>
    <%= link_to pic.nazwa, pic %><br>
    <% end %>
</div>
<%= link_to "Add New Picture", new_pic_path, class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

application.html.erb is a virgin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Obrazki</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to this line:

```
<%= @pics.each do |pic| %>
```

As I'm sure you're aware, the preceding `<%=` renders the result of the code to the HTML (while `<%` does not). The `each` method returns an `Enumerator` object, which is rendered similarly to an array and is what you see on the screen.

To fix it, just change the line to:

```
<% @pics.each do |pic| %>
```

Comment: omg what a stupid mistake! ofc it worked, thank you!